# Unix on the Mainframe: COB2 compiler, for Java calling COBOL

Tags: java, unix, cobol, mainframe

I've been working on trying to get COBOL and Java to interact with each other on the mainframe, and have run into trouble with specifically the cob2 compiler, which is the Unix on the mainframe equivalent.

I haven't seen many user experiences with this compiler online, so I was wondering if I asked a more direct question, people would reveal their insight.

IBM has several examples of Java calling COBOL DLL's either directly or indirectly, but they ultimately boil down to compile the COBOL as a dll, use System.load, compile Java and run.  These examples haven't worked for me for the following reasons.

When using cob2 with the -c option, it is purported to generate a .o object file.  This has not happened for me, although it did generate an empty .lst file.  I was able to get around this by simply skipping the -c step and compiling and linking using this series of commands:

```
`    sh ${COB2HOME}/bin/cob2 -o ${DIR}/c2jcr.o  
      -qdll,thread,case=mixed ${DIR}/c2jcr.cbl;
       ${COB2HOME}/bin/cob2                    
      -o ${DIR}/libc2jcr.so                    
      -bdll,case=mixed ${DIR}/c2jcr.o          
      ${JAVAHOME}/bin/j9vm/libjvm.x            
      ${COB2HOME}/lib/igzcjava.x               `
```

This appears to provide the .so library that is required for link with the Java program, but upon investigation of the load, and during run, the system declares that the LE CSECT CEESTART is not there.

Am I missing something in my cob2 library that has these LE modules, or somewhere in my scripting?  I tried pulling in loads from the mainframe compiled with the LE modules intact and ENTRY CEESTART explicitly stated in the link step, but could not get any further than "UnsatisfiedLinkError" with "Internal Error".

Any wisdom is greatly appreciated, especially if you've gone down a completely different route to call COBOL from Java.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you provide the command you were using where you claim that -c did not generate a .o file.

Comment: Yes sir, thanks for responding.

sh ${COB2HOME}/bin/cob2 -c                    
      -qdll,thread,case=mixed ${DIR}/c2jcr.cbl

Comment: Few more questions: Which compiler version are you using for COBOL? and is the error you are getting 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: LibraryName.ProgramName()V or
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: LibraryName (Not found in java.library.path)
or something else

Comment: COBOL 6.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/c2j/libc2jcr.so (EDC5234S The DLL cannot be loaded because it does not contain a CEESTART CSECT.)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibraryWithPath(ClassLoader.java:1028)
 at java.lang.System.load(System.java:501)                          
 at c2jjs.<clinit>(c2jjs.java:14)                                   
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)           
 at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:205)      
Could not find the main class: c2jjs.  Program will exit.

Answer (score 2):

After conferring with IBM, it turns out I had a couple things missing.

You must have a STEPLIB environment field set to the location of your COBOL compiler on the mainframe, so it can find your IGYCRCTL module.

Second, like other COBOL 5+ compiling, you must allocate a gargantuan amount of space in order to compile.  2 GB is not enough.  Since I don't have permission to reallocate this in Unix, I ran a BPXBATCH job with REGION=0M.

After those two changes, -c compiles came out as normally.  The "workaround" I provided in the question is completely incorrect.  You must use:

sh ${COB2HOME}/bin/cob2 -c -qdll,thread,case=mixed ${DIR}/${COBPROG}.cbl

as your compile step, and the rest is just linkage.